# How to hide a property Default value in my control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a property like this (I don't want it to be nullable like int?)

```
public int id{get;set;}
```

I have a TextBox that binded to id property

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding id}"/>
```

When my windows loaded my TextBox has a value as 0,how can i hide id default value from my TextBox

Comment: What do you mean? hide the textBox? Or put a special text when it is 0?

Comment: Just change the id field to nullable

Comment: @KishoreKumar I dont want change the id field to nullable

Comment: I think you are asking to display empty rather than 0 within your Textbox when id is null. please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter) like this:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(string))]
public class IntegerConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int intValue = (int)value;
        return intValue != 0 ? intValue.ToString() : string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int intValue = 0;
        int.TryParse((string)value, out intValue);
        return intValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the visibility property to collapse, or hidden

or if you mean you only want to hide it when the id = 0 then you should use a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using int, you can use string here as your ID and write your own validation. or you could use int? instead of int.

```
public int? id{get;set;}
```

**EDIT**
If you don't want id field to be changed to nullable, than just binding to a string or use a converter, but either way, you will need to implement your own validation by implementing [IDataErrorInfo](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-idataerrorinfo-for-validation-in-mvvm-with-silverlight-and-wpf/).

Comment: I dont want change the id field to nullable

Answer (score 0):

You can use another one TextBox with empty string inside the same grid and make it visible when the first TextBox has default value as 0.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox  Text="{Binding id}" x:Name="txtbox1"/>
    <TextBox Text="" Visibility="{Binding Text,ElementName=txtbox1,Converter={StaticResource StringToVisibility}}"
</Grid>
```

In the above code based on the Converter that we used, it will work in the template. You have to write in the converter that when text comes with "0", just make the second TextBox to be visible.

```
public class StringToVisibility : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string str = value.ToString();
            if (str.Equals("0"))
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what will happen when user input '0' into `textbox1` ?

Comment: Just it will place the Second TextBox with empty string over the txtbox1. So it will automatically hides the first..